# transform array of strings into custom structure

Tags: javascript

I need to convert this array of strings into a special structure
https://github.com/jonmiles/bootstrap-treeview

This is my Input String array:

```
******************
"productone"
"productone\level2\level3"
"productwo"
"productwo\level2\level3\level4"
"productwo\level2\level3.1\level4\level5"
"productwo\level2\level3.2\level4\level5"

 so can you imagine this:

"memory"
"memory\ram"
"memory\ram\ddr\sodimm\533mhz\4gb"
"memory\ram\ddr\sodimm\533mhz\8gb"
"memory\ram\ddr\sodimm\533mhz\16gb"
"memory\ram\ddr\sodimm2\633mh\4gb
"memory\ram\ddr\sodimm2\633mh\16gb
"memory\disk"
and so on....
*******************
```

And I need this Output (pay attention at return correct order output):

```
var jsondata = [
  {
  "text": "productone",
  "nodes":[ {"text": "level2",
            "nodes":[{"text": "level3"}]
           }]
  },
  {
  "text": "productwo",
   "nodes":[{"text": "level2"},
            "nodes":[{"text": "level3",
                        "nodes":[{text:level4}]
                    }]
            }]
  }    
}]
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: That's an array of objects, not JSON. JSON is what you get when you convert it to a string with `JSON.stringify()`.

Comment: why do you have an extra line for `productone`?

Comment: Split the string on backslash, then use a loop to create the nested objects.

Comment: StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592), and we also [don't answer homework questions](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166). Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solve my problem and I have transform to Javacript pure code this
[Brandon Clapp article](http://brandonclapp.com/arranging-an-array-of-flat-paths-into-a-json-tree-like-structure/)

Answer (score 1):

I threw away my previous answer to replace it with this one.

This should do exactly what you want.

```
var src = [
  "productone",
  "productone\\level2\\level3",
  "productwo\\level2\\level3\\level4",
  "productone\\level2\\dog",
  "productone\\level2\\dog\\bark",
  "productwo\\level2\\level3a\\level4a",
  "productwo\\level2\\level3\\level4\\level5",
  "productwo\\food\\desserts\\cookies",
  "productwo\\food\\desserts\\cakes",
  "productwo\\food\\desserts\\pies",
  "productone\\level2\\cat",
  "productone\\level2\\cat\\meow"
]

function tempToObj(temp) {
  var result = [];
  Object.keys(temp).forEach(
    function(key) {
      var obj = {
        text: key
      };

      var nodes = tempToObj(temp[key]);
      if (nodes.length > 0) {
        obj.nodes = nodes;
      }

      result.push(obj);
    }
  );

  return result;
}

function strsToObj(strList) {
  var result = [];
  var tempResult = {};

  function buildNode(parts, idx, obj) {
    var key = parts[idx];

    obj[key] = obj[key] || {};

    idx++;
    if (idx < parts.length) {
      buildNode(parts, idx, obj[key]);
    }
  }

  strList.forEach(
    function(str) {
      var parts = str.split('\\');
      buildNode(parts, 0, tempResult);
    }
  );

  return tempToObj(tempResult);
}

var obj = strsToObj(src);
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj,0,2));
```

I found it much easier to just build of an object structure and then convert it into the format you wanted. That simplified the parsing algorithm and yet prevents rebuilding everything each time.

The result of the code above is this:

```
[
  {
    "text": "productone",
    "nodes": [
      {
        "text": "level2",
        "nodes": [
          {
            "text": "level3"
          },
          {
            "text": "dog",
            "nodes": [
              {
                "text": "bark"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "text": "cat",
            "nodes": [
              {
                "text": "meow"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "text": "productwo",
    "nodes": [
      {
        "text": "level2",
        "nodes": [
          {
            "text": "level3",
            "nodes": [
              {
                "text": "level4",
                "nodes": [
                  {
                    "text": "level5"
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "text": "level3a",
            "nodes": [
              {
                "text": "level4a"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "text": "food",
        "nodes": [
          {
            "text": "desserts",
            "nodes": [
              {
                "text": "cookies"
              },
              {
                "text": "cakes"
              },
              {
                "text": "pies"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Yes,  this is very good solution, but unfortunately don't respect the sorting of the array

Comment: I have to say that it would have been nice to see all of your requirements in your original question.

Comment: I'm really sorry, really, really a great help. Unfortunately I after the test I observe the problems. Thanks you very much

Answer (score 0):

You can `string#split` each string inside `array#map` and use `array#reduceRight` to check for `nodes` and `text` value inside your result object. If `text` key is present at a level, reassign your object to `nodes` key and populate `text` key with the current `text` value.

```js
var strings = ["productone","productone\\level2\\level3","productwo\\level2\\level3\\level4"];

const result = strings.map(string => string.split('\\').reduceRight((r,text, index) => {
  if(r['text'])
    r['nodes'] = [Object.assign({}, r)];
  r['text'] = text;
  return r;
},{}));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: This solution duplicate productone... so Is not a valid solution.
I need to check every time the values but I don't know how

Answer (score 0):

You could take a hash table with a nested approach by taking the given part strings as identifiert for nested objects for collecting all data.

Later this proposal deletes unwanted nodes without content.

This approach works for unsorted data.

```js
var array = ["productone", "productone\\level2\\level3", "productwo\\level2\\level3\\level4"],
    result = [],
    hash = { _: result };

array.forEach(function (a) {
    a.split('\\').reduce(function (r, k) {
        if (!r[k]) {
            r[k] = { _: [] };
            r._.push({ text: k, nodes: r[k]._ });
        }
        return r[k];
    }, hash);
});

result.forEach(function clean(o) {
    if (o.nodes.length) {
        o.nodes.forEach(clean);
    } else {
        delete o.nodes;
    }
});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```